# Migrating live wordpress site to local, get weird error on sub page

Tags: wordpress

So I'm trying to work on an existing Wordpress site locally with the end goal of building a custom plugin. I've copied the database and files, updated the wp-config file and updated any links in posts. I can access homepage just fine on localhost but for any other pages I just get

```
Error thrown
Using $this when not in object context
```

With no line for this error and there's nothing in the logs I can find either, so I'm at a loss for where to start looking for how to fix this. Even pointing me a direction would be very helpful

Comment: first deactivate all plugins. if the error dissapear, then you should to activate them one by one and check every time, on which plugin activating the error occured. if after deactivating all of them you get the error, then change theme to default.

Comment: about the error. it looks like in the code, which throwing the error, used exceptions. try to find soething like `catch` , `try` in the plugin/theme, when you fined which one throw error